# problems with passing pointer values in a c function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Hey i have a program that checks for the longest sequence in an array and I need it to tell me from what point does the sequence starts, I used a pointer for that in the function but it seems not to update its value outside of the function.the pointer points to NULL but at first it pointed to a
and still didnt change.

Comment: You are passing `begin` by value. You need to pass a reference - in this case a pointer-to-pointer: `int longestSequence(int a[], int n ,int** begin){`

Comment: You posted an *almost* [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but there is no `#include <...>` and there are typos with, and incomplete, `{`braces`}`. (And horrible code formatting). And it would be better to flag the code like with a comment and not confuse it with `***begin=&a[i];***` as if you are a 3-star programmer.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp ive tried that and it crashes after typing the array

Comment: Did you also change `longestresult=longestSequence(a,n, &begin);` and `*begin=&a[i];`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I did change the *begin=&a[i]; but it dosent accept adding the & and dosent compile

Comment: @WeatherVane noted changed and in the futre I will go by the guidlines

Comment: You have to change the prototype too. It compiles fine here: https://ideone.com/eQFgEw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for loop need to be checked also...

```
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
..
}
```

One idea whic may help you understand things a bit better about pointer is it is nothing different than an ordinary variable (it holds address as its value).

Now here you need that value (`begin`'s value) to change so you need to pointer to that.

so you pass address of begin which is a pointer

```
func(..,&begin);
func(...,int** begin)
{
  .. 
}
```

If I am a type in C then pointer to me will be named `coderredoc *` and pointer to that will be `coderredoc **` and so on.

---

So you want to change the value of begin what should you do?

you assign anything to that address .. `*begin=...`

---

```
+---------+
|   int   |address:0x7777
| begin   |
+---------+
     /\
      |
      |
      -----------+--------------------------- +
                 |  pointer to begin (pbegin) | (int*)
                 |  0x7777                    |
                 +----------------------------+
```

---

```
int longestSequence(int a[], int n,int *elem ){
        int length=1,i,maxvalue=0,lastseen=a[0],mpos=0;
        for(i=1;i<n;i++)
            {
                if(a[i-1]==a[i])
                {
                    length++;
                }
                else
                {
                     lastseen= a[i];
                     if(length>maxvalue)
                     {
                        maxvalue=length;
                        mpos = pos;
                     }
                     pos=i;
                     length=1;
                }
             if(length>maxvalue)
                     {
                        maxvalue=length;
                        mpos = pos;
                     }

            }
            *elem=mpos; //mpos position of the starting of the longest sequence
            return maxvalue;
    }
```

Return the maximum length and we pass pointer to an integer variable which will contain the maximum element.

In main you call :  `int legth=longestSequence(a,n,&longestSequenceElement);`

Comment: thanks your comment and the one above you helped me understand this topic better

Comment: Glad it helped...as an hint you dont need to use pointer here simply return an integer from the function...

Comment: @Pizzatags.: check my answer

Comment: what is mpos=pos ?

Comment: @Pizzatags.: I have added a bit of comment and changed the code a bit..check my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much I have edited my code to the final version that works that added bit of comment helped me

Answer (score 0):

C uses pass by value (always). So when you pass `begin` it is the value of `begin` you pass. No matter how many times you change it inside function A, the value of `begin` is unchanged in the code calling function A.

If you want function A to change the value of `begin` in the function that called function A, you must pass a pointer to `begin` instead of the value of `begin`.

Like:

```
int longestSequence(int a[], int n, int** begin);    
                                       ^^^
```

and call it like

```
longestSequence(a, n, &begin);
```

In the function use

```
*begin = ....
```

to change the value.

Then the changes will be visible **after** the function returns.

Comment: thanks but it seems I cant use ** in my function and will have to write it in a diffrent way,